# How to add single(') or double(") quotes to a String in pascal?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to add quotation marks `"` or `'` to a list of strings, which will be used in a SQL query. The system is using Firebird 2.5.

This query has a `not in` clause and I am looking for the query to have the following format:

```sql
Select c.codes
From Table c
where c.cuit not in ("20-11111111","20-11111111","20-11111111".....to n codes)
```

This procedure loads the string list from a grid:

```pascal
function loadCodesFromGrid(): WideString;
var
  slAux: TStringList;
  wsAux : WideString;
  stTable: String;
  qCliProv: TFXQuery;
  niCol : Integer;
begin
  niCol := 1;    
  for n := 1 to gDetails.RowCount - 1 do //load cuit from grid. The cuit in my country is like the social security number in United States

    if Trim(gDetails.Cells[niCol, n]) <> '' then
      wsAux := wsAux + iif((Trim(wsAux) = ''), '',  ',') + Trim(gDetails.Cells[3, n]);
    
    slAux :=  fxFormatQuery(wsAux ); 
       
    try
      qCliProv.SQL.Text :=
        ' Select Code' + iif(pboClients, Copy(stTable, 0, 7), Copy(stTable, 0, 9)) + ' As Code' +
        '   From ' + stTable +
        '  Where Active = 1 ';
    
      if slAux.Count > 0 then
        for n := 0 to slAux.Count - 1 do
        begin
          if Trim(slAux.Strings[n]) = '' then
            Continue;
    
          qCliProv.SQL.Add(
            '    And Cuit Not In (' + slAux.Strings[n] + ')'  );
        end;
    
        qCliProv.Open;
        //the rest of the code is not important
```

This function formats the query:

```pascal
function fxFormatQuerySQL(pstClients: WideString): TStringList;
var
  slAux, slAuxResult: TStringList;
  niI, niLine: Integer;
begin
  niLine := 0;
    
  slAuxResult := TStringList.Create;
  slAux := TStringList.Create;
    
  try
    slAuxResultado.Add('"'); // 
    
    slAux.Delimiter := ',';
    slAux.DelimitedText := pstClients;
    
    for niI := 0 to slAux.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if ((Frac(niI/100) = 0) and (nII <> 0)) then
      begin
        Inc(niLine);
        slAuxResult.Add('');
      end;
    
      slAuxResult.Strings[niLine] := slAuxResult.Strings[niLine] +
        iif((slAuxResult.Strings[niLine] = ''), '', ',' )  + slAux.Strings[niI];
    end;
    
    Result := slAuxResult;
    
  finally
    FreeAndNil(slAux);
  end;
end;
```

I have tried a lot of changes, but I can't get the query to be generated in the format I want.

Comment: `nil` is a horrible variable name. I'm surprised that code compiles. `nil` is a reserved word in Pascal, and is used to indicate a non-assigned pointer or object reference. It's not a loop counter variable. You're writing code that is going to be very hard for anyone else to understand or maintain, and that in some circumstances could introduce a very hard to identify bug. I'd strongly advise you to use something else. I typically use `i` or `x` for loop counter variables, as that's the only place I use single letter variable names.

Comment: It is nii with the last i in capital letters. it is legacy code and and yes has horrible named variables. now I change the name of the variable

Comment: Pascal is not case-sensitive, so `nil`, `NIL` and `niL` are all the same as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: Yes, I know . but the last letter is an i not an L. I already changed the name of the variable

Comment: It is much better for security reasons to use parameters in the query instead of building the SQL string. Not totally trivial with a variable number of parameters but completely doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not formatting the `not in` clause correctly.  And you are performing the SQL query on each grid row individually, which defeats the purpose of using a `not in` clause at all.

You also don't need the `fxFormatQuery()` function at all.  You can use the RTL's `AnsiQuotedStr()` function to handle the quotes for you.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
function loadCodesFromGrid(): String;
var
  slAux: TStringList;
  wsAux, stTable: String;
  qCliProv: TFXQuery;
  I: Integer;
begin    
  ...

  slAux := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 1 to gDetails.RowCount - 1 do
    begin
      if Trim(gDetails.Cells[1, I]) <> '' then
      begin
        wsAux := Trim(gDetails.Cells[3, I]);
        if wsAux <> '' then
          slAux.Add(AnsiQuotedStr(wsAux, '"'));
      end;
    end;

    qCliProv.SQL.Text :=
      ' Select Code' + Copy(stTable, 0, iif(pboClients, 7, 9)) + ' As Code' +
      '   From ' + stTable +
      '  Where Active = 1 ';
    
    if slAux.Count > 0 then
    begin
      slAux.Delimiter := ',';
      slAux.QuoteChar := #0;
      qCliProv.SQL.Add(
        '    And Cuit Not In (' + slAux.DelimitedText + ')' );
    end;
  finally
    slAux.Free;
  end;

  qCliProv.Open;

  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just quote the elements you are generating in `fxFormatQuerySQL` with

```
+ AnsiQuotedStr(slAux.Strings[niI], '"')
```

instead of

```
+ slAux.Strings[niI];
```